# Uploading images in Django, hopefully a step-by-step guide?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-settings, django-media

OK, so I must totally be missing something here...

For clarification this is with Django 1.9.7

My model has a field:

```
prop_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT, null = True, blank = True, max_length=500)
```

I have imported settings, so I don't think the problem is here.

That said, my settings has:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

MEDIA_URL = '/perform/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'perform/media')
```

The media is stored in:

```
PerformPy/perform/media/
```

(`perform` is the app name)

The BASE_DIR is the absolute path to root directory `PerformPy`.

The urls.py I am using is (I believe this is where the problem is):

```
urlpatterns = [ ... ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Finally, the line(s) I've tried using in the template, `index.html` as follows, all with 404 errors (unless otherwise noted):

1. src="/perform/media/{{prop.prop_image | filename }}" (using a template tag to filter out file name)
2. src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/{{prop.prop_image | filename}}"
3. src="{{MEDIA_ROOT}}/{{prop.prop_image | filename}}"
4. src="{{MEDIA_ROOT}}/{{prop.prop_image.url}}" [ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED]
5. src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/{{prop.prop_image.url}}" [ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED]
6. src="{{prop.prop_image.url}}
7. src="/perform/media/{{prop.prop_image.url}}
8. src="{{prop.prop_image}} [Not allowed to use local resource]
9. src="/{{prop.prop_image}}"
10. src="perform/media/{{prop.prop_image}}"
11. src="perform/media/{{prop.prop_image_url}}"

Any thoughts or suggestions would be immensely helpful! I am pretty new at this so it is likely I made a dumb mistake.

Comment: go into shell and get a prop instance then run ```prop.prop_image.url``` - let me know what it says

Comment: Output is: `/perform/media/c%3A/Users/My%20User%20Name/Documents/Private%20Documents/Other%20Documents/Programs/Program%20Docs/PerformPy%20v2/PerformPy/perform/media/prop.jpg`

Comment: that looks wrong... %3A is a colon ```:``` - what does  ```settings.MEDIA_ROOT``` output?

Comment: `c:\Users\My User Name\Documents\Private Documents\Other Documents\Programs\Program Docs\PerformPy v2\PerformPy\perform/media`

Comment: In `settings.py`: `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'perform/media')`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120647/discussion-between-luke-aus-and-user3684314).